# Stored procedure for money transfer in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsql-package

Hope this task find you well.

```
Please help me out with this,

My requirement is to transfer money from one account to another account which is in a same table.
the procedure should have 3 in parameters,
They are,
--> from_account_number
--> To_account_number
--> Credit_amount
```

Actual data:

```
acc_num        acc_bal
12345          50000
67890          40000
```

Expected data:

```
eg: exec trans_sp(12345,67890,10000);
```

```
ac_num   ac_bal
12345    40000
67890    60000
```

```
`trans_sp`
```

Comment: Subtract from one account and add to another; should be fairly simple. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option (with no controls at all; add them yourself):

Before:

```
SQL> select * from money;

ACCOUNT_NU     AMOUNT
---------- ----------
12345           10000
65789           20000
86420           30000
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure trans_sp (par_acc_from in varchar2, par_acc_to in varchar2, par_amount in number)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    update money set
  5      amount = amount - par_amount
  6      where account_number = par_acc_from;
  7
  8    update money set
  9      amount = amount + par_amount
 10      where account_number = par_acc_to;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec trans_sp('86420', '12345', 5000);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from money;

ACCOUNT_NU     AMOUNT
---------- ----------
12345           15000
65789           20000
86420           25000

SQL>
```